# Aplicação web para várias pessoas

Tags: banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Vejo muitos aplicativos web que podem ser utilizados por várias empresas.

Como eles fazem isso? Eles criam apenas um banco e compartilham entre esses vários clientes?

Por exemplo:

> A empresa A tem 10 usuários e a empresa B tem 5 usuários deste
> sistema.

Eles usam bancos de dados diferentes a empresa A e B, ou através do mapeamento relacional das tabelas se consegue isso?

Ou qual tecnologia empregam para isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem as duas formas e até mesma uma forma híbrida (parte da aplicação acessa banco compartilhado e parte usa isolado). Isso ainda pode variar se são empresas clientes diferentes ou empresas dentro do grupo. Cada uma com suas vantagens.

Não há tecnologia específica, pode ser aplicado virtualmente em qualquer tecnologia.

Uma das formas desta técnica é chamada [*multitenancy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). A aplicação se torna *multitenant*.

Particularmente, na imensa maioria dos casos, acho que ter um banco de dados para cada empresa é melhor solução. Dá mais flexibilidade para escalar, para personalizar, é mais fácil dar mais segurança, enfim, tem um monte de vantagens específicas que não vem ao caso. Dá mais trabalho para atualizar, tem mais custos. Dá para automatizar até certo ponto, em tempos de Devops não deveria ser problema. Depende da aplicação, depende da necessidade de consolidação dos dados e uma série de outros fatores técnicos e políticos. Dá trabalho extra manter tudo como se fosse uma coisa só.

Em alguns casos não precisa ter bancos separados, mas sim *schemas*.

Se tiver dúvidas específicas aplicando a técnica, vai postando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Considera que usar apenas um banco não seja tão vantajoso @bigown?

Comment: É o velho depende :) Tudo tem suas vantagens. Mas em geral, sim.

Comment: haha, nem vou levar essa discussão muito pra frente senão seriam 50++ comentários

Comment: comentários, acho que você viu antes de eu editar

Comment: Separar em schemas acho a melhor solução, eu só separaria em bancos diferentes se fosse uma mega aplicação, ou se o cliente exigisse

Comment: Estou com essa mesma dúvida em um cenário com asp.net-mvc e postgre em um sistema que irá gerar os bancos de forma dinâmica. Nesses passados 3 anos, gostaria de saber mais sobre o assunto. Ou até solicitar uma possível "atualização" de resposta. Rs

Comment: @RBZ entre o "comentar" em azul na pergunta e o "1 Resposta" tem solução pra respostas desatualizadas :)

Comment: "Oferecer uma recompensa" !?  (tive que ir no modo desktop no celular, me trolou haha)