# Estrutura Web API para vários clientes

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenancy

Eu estou com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma aplicação Web que acessa os dados por intermédio de uma WebAPI C#. Preciso aplicar o conceito de [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) nela, de modo a permitir que a minha aplicação seja acessada por vários clientes e que cada cliente acesse o seu banco de dados individualmente.

Diante desta necessidade, pesquisei no SOPt e encontrei as seguintes questões:

[Aplicação web para várias pessoas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85591/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web-para-v%c3%a1rias-pessoas)

[Bancos de dados para Clientes diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17095/bancos-de-dados-para-clientes-diferentes/17135#17135)

Quanto ao conceito eu entendi, porém minha dúvida é quanto ao deploy da minha WebAPI e qual seria a melhor prática:

Devo realizar o Deploy e hospedar uma única instância da API no IIS (e redirecionar o acesso ao banco de dados via código)?

Ou devo realizar o Deploy individualizado, ou seja, hospedar inúmeras instâncias da API no IIS, cada qual acessando o seu banco de dados?

No caso de a segunda opção ser a mais viável, existe alguma maneira de fazer esse deploy múltiplo de forma mais automatizada? Existe algum recurso cloud que possibilita este escalonamento de deploy (Azure, Amazon, etc...)?

Comment: Clarificação - quando você diz 'cada qual acessando o seu banco de dados', você quer dizer que cada cliente terá seus dados armazenados em instâncias de banco exclusivas, ou foi apenas uma expressão (dados de vários clientes em um mesmo banco)?

Comment: @MeiaEsquerda, é exatamente isso, cada cliente com uma instância de banco de dados exclusiva. Para se ter uma idéia, atualmente a nossa necessidade é para em torno de 100 clientes.

Comment: Seu custo de manutenção da estrutura será consideravelmente maior. Também imagine que sempre que você alterar o modelo o patch deverá ser aplicado em 100+ instâncias - isso, se você não permitir que bancos estejam em versões diferentes de patching.

Comment: @MeiaEsquerda, realmente, a intenção esta pergunta é levantar qual seria a melhor prática e o que é mais utilizado ou como a comunidade atua neste tipo de situação.

Comment: Uma dúvida. Sempre que houver alguma atualização todos os clientes deverão ser atualizados?

Comment: @Randrade, ai vai o famoso depende... Hoje sim todos terão a mesma atualização, mais podem ocorrer situações onde existe algo específico, da forma que trabalhamos hoje isso é resolvido programaticamente com patterns e orientação a objeto.

Comment: Esse sistema utiliza o modelo [SaaS (Software como Serviço)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o)?

Comment: @Randrade, sim, nossa idéia inicial é essa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla. Vou tentar prover alguns parâmetros que lhe ajudarão a escolher seu cenário ideal.

- **Bancos de dados individuais** garantem isolamento de dados (um usuário de um cliente não verá dados de outro). Por outro lado, seu custo de manutenção da estrutura será consideravelmente maior - imagine que sempre que você alterar o modelo o patch deverá ser aplicado em 100+ instâncias. Esse cenário se complica ainda mais se você permitir que bancos estejam em versões diferentes de *patching*.
  Adicionalmente você precisará de um repositório exclusivamente para prover **tenancy scope** - um banco onde clientes e seus usuários são cadastrados.
- Um **bancos de dados compartilhado** simplifica seu processo de patching, porém necessita de um esforço maior para guarantir isolamento - interfaces de pesquisa devem *sempre* levar em consideração o cliente ao qual o usuário está associado.
- A **API** pode ter seu escopo parametrizado sem a necessidade de centenas de *deploys*. Algumas políticas de uso que podem ser úteis são a de **definição de escopo por credenciais**, onde o escopo de dados a ser utilizado é definido após o sign-in do usuário, ou **por domínio**, onde tanto `cliente1.api.empresa.br` quando `cliente2.api.empresa.br` estão mapeados para `api.empresa.br`, e internamente sua API escolhe o escopo de dados de acordo com o subdomínio acessado ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681028/how-to-get-sub-domain-on-web-api-action)).

Comment: No exemplo citado de definição de escopo por domínio, eu tenho que fazer essa verificação no Startup da API? e utilizar os dados do subdomínio para validar qual cliente está acessando?

Comment: @JulioBorges Essa avaliação deve acontecer para toda chamada à API. Não conheço seu modelo, porém se um usuário possuir privilégios em dois ou mais domínios então será necessário armazenar seus detalhes no banco de *tenancy scope*.